# django internationalization: counter is not available when marking strings for pluralization

Tags: django, internationalization

Adding plural to django stings in the code should use `ungettext()`, where the 3rd parameter is the counter to decide whether it should use singular or plural:

```
text = ungettext(
        'There is %(count)d %(name)s available.',
        'There are %(count)d %(name)s available.',
        count
) % {
    'count': count,
    'name': name
}
```

The parameter as counter should be available when `ungettext()` is called. But in my case, the string and the counter is separated so it's impossible to supply the counter at the right place:

```
class foo(bar):
    description="There is %(count)d %(names)s available."

class foo_2(bar):
    description="%(count)d rabbits jump over the %(names)s."

# More 'foo' type classes....

class foo_model(Model):
    count=IntegerField()
    name=CharField()
    klass=CharField()
    #model definition...

    def _get_self_class(self):
        if self.klass=='foo':
            return foo
        elif self.klass=='foo_2':
            return foo_2

    def get_description(self):
            return self._get_self_class.description%(self.count,self.name)
```

I'm a bit of stuck with how to internationalize this. Does anybody has a good idea?

**Update:**

I've changed the example to a closer match of my situation

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct `ungettext` somewhere, for example

```
class Foo(Bar):
    description = "There is %(count)d %(names)s available."
    description_plural = "There are %(count)d %(names)s available."

class FooModel(Model):
    count = IntegerField()
    name = CharField()
    # model definition...

    def get_description(self):
        return ungettext(Foo.description, Foo.description_plural, self.count) % \
                   {'count':self.count, 'name':self.name}
```

Comment: @XunYang `makemessage` relies on `xgettext` which scans py file directly to find the *'ungettext'* literal. You could run `xgettext` through the file to see if the msgs get collected.

Comment: I've modified the example to a closer match, where I used one return for different types of 'foo'. Not sure if a direct scan can find all those strings :(

Comment: @XunYang The strings cannot collected by `xgettext` they must appear inside `ungettext`